# How to access environmental variables inside sshpass interactive mode

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, heredoc, sshpass

The below shell script snippet prints the environmental variable outside of sshpass, but not inside.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $1 = '' ]] && BRANCH="develop" || BRANCH=$1

echo $DESTINATION_FOLDER // prints from env

sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER <<-'ENDSSH'

    echo $DESTINATION_FOLDER // doesn't print anything, output: empty

    exit
ENDSSH
```

Am I missing any option to be passed to the interactive mode with **sshpass** so that it can read environmental variables defined in the local system?

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Environment variables aren't generally copied over ssh connections; are you expecting them to be?

Comment: @GordonDavisson - hmmm i am just curious if the local env variables are able to access inside sshpass environment once loggedIn? I am not sure if this is supported or not too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to replace `'ENDSSH'` with `ENDSSH` to allow bash to interpret the variable in your here-document.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells

Comment: This worked, thank you